# How to extract and send data having multiple and varying models in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory

So I have angular.js App, in which  form has basically 2 models. But first model can have multiple instances

For e.g. Journal can  have more than 1 author.

It is not constant how many instances of first model will be there, user can add as many he likes.

Right now I am extracting fields using

```
 var form = $("#form");
            var response = JSON.stringify(form.serializeArray());
            BuilderAPIService.make(response).success(function(response){
               alert("Done");
            });
```

Issue with this is that it gives me name value pairs, however I want key-value as it is more easy to handle.
What is the most effective way to extract and send form data to server so that it is easy to manipulate data?

Comment: @StaffordWilliams-Code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The journal data should contain a list of authors. This means your json object should look like:

```
journal= {
   name :'test  1',
   description :'test description',
   authors : [ 
             {author_name:'James', author_age: 38},
             {author_name:'Kate',author_age: 25}
            ]
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that should do it but how do I extract from form to this manner. They way I am doing is using serializeArray to JSON,but gives me name value pairs (I prefer key value pairs)

Comment: could you provide a plunker with your form and a simple controller example to show how exactly you have it there?